# NPM is throwing Type expected while build react/nextjs project after adding use-places-autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, npm-install

I am getting this error upon building my react/nextjs project.
I have tried to open vs code as an administrator but still facing this issue.

```
./node_modules/use-places-autocomplete/dist/index.d.ts:21:24
Type error: Type expected.

  19 |   export type Suggestion = google.maps.places.AutocompletePrediction;
  20 | 
> 21 |   export type Status = `${google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus}` | "";
     |                        ^
```

Windows 10 machine
Node version 14.17.5
Package.json
react 17.0.2
typescript ^3.7.2

Upgarding ts to 4.1.0 gives this error ->  `E/launcher - Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with TS version. I upgraded to 4.3.2 and it worked!